# Connection issues with Amazon S3 Rails 3.1.1 and Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm upgrading my rails app using Paperclip and uploading my attachments via ftp (using paperclipftp gem).  I'm currently in my development environment which includes Rails 3.1.1, Ruby ruby 1.9.2p290, paperclip 3.0.4, aws-sdk 1.8.1.2
I've made changes to my app to utilize the aws-sdk gem to utilize amazon s3 for my attachment storage.  Here's what I have in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'web-app-theme', '~> 0.8.0'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'tinymce-rails'
gem 'cocaine', '~> 0.3.2'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

In my model I define the attachment with:

```
#paperclip
  has_attached_file :upload,
     :styles => Proc.new { |attach| attach.instance.attachment_styles },
     :storage => :s3,
     :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join('config', 's3.yml'),
     :path => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
     :url => "http://" + FTP_CONFIG['file_host'] + "/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

My s3.yml file looks like:

```
development:
  bucket: a36-dev
  access_key_id: #########
  secret_access_key: ##########

test:
  bucket: a36-test
  access_key_id: #########
  secret_access_key: #########

production:
  bucket: a36-prod
  access_key_id: #########
  secret_access_key: #########
```

The error I continue to get is:
Errno::ECONNABORTED in MediaController#create_for_content 
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Here's the stack trace:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:235:in `syswrite'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:235:in `do_write'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:249:in `write'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:191:in `write0'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:167:in `block in write'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:182:in `writing'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:166:in `write'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1756:in `send_request_with_body_stream'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1726:in `exec'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1189:in `transport_request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/net/http/connection_pool/session.rb:64:in `request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/net/http/connection_pool.rb:173:in `block in request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/net/http/connection_pool.rb:194:in `session_for'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/net/http/connection_pool.rb:171:in `request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/net/http/connection_pool/connection.rb:173:in `request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/core/http/net_http_handler.rb:66:in `handle'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/core/client.rb:230:in `block in make_sync_request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/core/client.rb:266:in `retry_server_errors'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/core/client.rb:226:in `make_sync_request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/core/client.rb:451:in `block (2 levels) in client_request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/core/client.rb:334:in `log_client_request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/core/client.rb:420:in `block in client_request'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/core/client.rb:316:in `return_or_raise'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/core/client.rb:419:in `client_request'
(eval):3:in `put_object'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:1649:in `write_with_put_object'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.1.2/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:600:in `write'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.0.4/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:313:in `block in flush_writes'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.0.4/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:299:in `each'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.0.4/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:299:in `flush_writes'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.0.4/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:200:in `save'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.0.4/lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:17:in `block in save_attached_files'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.0.4/lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:10:in `block in each_attachment'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.0.4/lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:9:in `each'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.0.4/lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:9:in `each_attachment'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.0.4/lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:16:in `save_attached_files'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:401:in `_run_save_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:37:in `save'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
app/controllers/media_controller.rb:207:in `create_for_content'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__690981913__process_action__778841897__callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.9/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.9/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.9/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.9/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.9/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.9/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.9/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.9/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

I can't figure out why I keep getting this error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just started seeing this my self. Any luck figuring it out?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and remembered I had recently update my aws-sdk, paperclip, cocaine gems. What I ended up doing was locking paperclip to version "3.0.4", aws-sdk to the latest version "~> 1.8.3.1", and locking cocaine at "0.3.2". This solves problems with imagemagick and amazon. I know that does not really fix the problem but it is working for me.